# jquery: button mousedown state change

Tags: jquery, button, mouseevent, toggleclass

OK this should be easy but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have a button, when I click on it I want it to change state, but only for as long as the the button is being pressed, like any OS native button.

So here is my code...

```
$('button').live('mousedown', function(){

    $(this).addClass('down');

}).live('mouseup', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('down');
});
```

Looks simple enough right... but this doesn't work.  When you click on it, the state does change... but it stays that way... the mouseup event only works the second time you click on it.

This also happens with toggleClass and when I execute the code from the focus/blur event.

What is going on here, and how can I make it work properly?

Comment: working fine on chrome... [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/NPtGx/) jQuery 1.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider using CSS instead, as it's much faster for display purposes than adding/removing a class via Javascript:

```
button:active { /* this is the mousedown pseudoelement */ }
input:focus, textarea:focus { /* this represents text input fields with focus */ }
```

Comment: Thanks. Its always better to do this stuff with plain css when you can.

Comment: This does not work. After you click the button, it remains "active" until you click somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The original solution posted  by *cybermotron* written in jQuery works perfect for me on Chrome, Firefox and IE.

In case it does not work, perhaps setting a timeout of about 200ms on the mouseup function will improve the functionality. Not everything you want to do is a class.

Comment: This does not work - the mouseup handler is not called if you press the mouse down, drag the mouse off of the "button" and then release.